# Recurrent machine learning ETL using Luigi

Tags: python, amazon-s3, machine-learning, etl, luigi

Today, running the machine learning job I've written is done by hand. I download the needed input files, learn and predict things, output a .csv file, which I then copy into a database.

However, since this is going into production, I need to automate all this process. The needed input files will arrive every month (and eventually more frequently) into a S3 bucket from the provider.

Now I'm planning using Luigi to solve this problem. Here is the ideal process:

- Every week (or day, or hour, whatever I feel is better) I need my program to watch the S3 bucket for new files
- When a file arrives, my machine learning pipeline is fired, and spits some pandas dataframes.
- After that, I need my program to write these results into different DBs

The problem is, I don't know how to use Luigi to automate:

1. File watching
2. Schedule tasks (e.g. for every month)
3. Deploy it (in a reproducible manner)

Today, here is the pipeline skeleton that I have in mind:

```
import luigi

from mylib import ml_algorithm
from mytools import read_s3, write_hdfs, read_hdfs, write_db, new_files, mark_as_done

class Extract(luigi.Task):
    date = luigi.DateParameter()
    s3_path = luigi.Parameter()
    filename = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires(self):
        pass
    def output(self, filename):
        luigi.hdfs.HdfsTarget(self.date.strftime('data/%Y_%m_%d' + self.filename)
    def run(self):
        data = read_s3(s3_path + '/' + file)
        with self.output.open('w') as hdfs_file:
            write_hdfs(hdfs_file, data)


class Transform(luigi.Task):
    date = luigi.DateParameter()
    s3_path = luigi.Parameter()
    filename = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires(self):
        return Extract(self.date, self.s3_path, self.filename)
    def output(self, filename):
        luigi.hdfs.HdfsTarget(self.date.strftime('data/results/%Y_%m_%d_' + filename)
    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as inputfile:
            data = read_hdfs(inputfile)
        result = ml_algorithm(data)
        with self.output().open('w') as outputfile:
            write_hdfs(outputfile, result)
        mark_as_done(filename)



class Load(luigi.Task):
    date = luigi.DateParameter()
    s3_path = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires(self):
        return [Transform(self.date, self.s3_path, filename) for filename in new_files(self.s3_path)]
    def output(self):
        # Fake DB target, just for illustrative purpose
        luigi.hdfs.DBTarget('...')
    def run(self):
        for input in self.input():
            with input.open('r') as inputfile:
                result = read_hdfs(inputfile)
            # again, just for didatic purposes
            db = self.output().connection
            write_db(db, result)
```

Then I would add this to crontab and simply wrap into a Docker container.

Questions:

- Is this the correct pattern that people use to do this? Is there a better way to do it?
- If I had `Transform1` (that depends on the input data) and `Transform2` (that depends on `Transform1` result) and wanted to save both results into different DBs, how could one implement this using a Luigi pipeline (also in this context of watching files)?
- Do people use something different than cron for this?
- How to containerize this properly?

Comment: Just to clarify, an example of a multi-step ETL is: input data is a user table, each user with some features, the first transformation can be fill a column containing missing values, and the second transformation can be a clustering of that users. I would like to save both the filled table and the clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern looks largely correct. I would start by using a cron job to call a script that triggers the `Load` task pipeline. It looks like this `Load` task already verifies the existence of new files in the S3 bucket, but you would have to change the output to also be conditional, which could be a status file or something else if there is nothing to do. You could also do this in a higher level `WrapperTask` (with no output) that just required the `Load` task only if there were new files. Then you could use this `WrapperTask` to require two different Load tasks and which would respectively require your `Transform1` and `Transform2`.

Adding in containers... what my cron really calls is a script that pulls my latest code from git, builds a new container if necessary, and then calls docker run. I have another container that is always up running `luigid`. The daily docker run executes a shell script in the container using `CMD` that calls the luigi task with the parameters needed for that day.

Comment: But what if Transform1 depends on Transform2? This way I can't use a single wrapper task to call both, since they are dependent. I also don't understand how to change the output conditionally.

Comment: You can add Transform2 to the `requires()` of Transform1. Even if the WrapperTask requires both, luigi will figure out the right graph. Making the output conditional is a bit hacky, probably better to just have the WrapperTask.