# Luigi task doesn't fire up the requirements on ETL process

Tags: python, luigi

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773915/recurrent-machine-learning-etl-using-luigi), regarding the pattern to follow in a recurrent ETL process.

Today, running the machine learning job I've written is done by hand. I download the needed input files, learn and predict things, output a .csv file, which I then copy into a database.

However, since this is going into production, I need to automate all this process. The needed input files will arrive every month (and eventually more frequently) into a S3 bucket from the provider.

As an example, I tried to implement this in Luigi, but changing S3 to a local directory, so things would be simpler. This program should

- Watch the input directory for new files
- When some new file is found, extract it to the data directory by the `Extract` task
- Process by the `Transform` task (using the `algorithm` function)
- It's loaded to the PostgreSQL database on the `Load` task

---

```
import glob

import luigi
from luigi.contrib import postgres
import pandas as pd


class ReadFile(luigi.ExternalTask):
    # Simply load the new file from input directory 
    filename = luigi.Parameter()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.hdfs.LocalTarget('input/' + self.filename)


class Extract(luigi.Task):
    # Extract from input directory and put in the data directory
    filename = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires(self):
        return ReadFile(self.filename)
    def output(self):
        return luigi.hdfs.LocalTarget('data/' + self.filename)
    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as input_file:
            data = input_file.read()
        with self.output().open('w') as output_file:
            write(output_file, data)


class Transform(luigi.Task):
    # Transform the file from data directory using the transform function
    filename = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires(self):
        return Extract(self.filename)
    def output(self, filename):
        return luigi.hdfs.LocalTarget('results/' + self.filename)
    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as input_file:
            data = input_file.read()
        result = trasnform(data)
        with self.output().open('w') as output_file:
            result.to_csv(output_file)
        mark_as_done(self.filename)


class Load(luigi.Task):
    # Find new files, run the Transform function and load into the PostgreSQL DB
    date = luigi.DateParameter()
    def requires(self):
        return [Transform(filename) for filename in new_files('input/')]
    def output(self):
        return postgres.PostgresTarget(host='db', database='luigi', user='luigi', password='luigi', table='test', update_id=self.date)
    def run(self):
        for input in self.input():
            with input.open('r') as inputfile:
                result = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
            connection = self.output().connect()
            for row in result.itertuples():
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)', row)

# Get connection to the SQLite DB, which will store the files that were already processed
SQLITE_CONNECTION = None
def get_connection():
    if SQLITE_CONNECTION is None:
         SQLITE_CONNECTION = sqlite3.connect('processed.db')
    return SQLITE_CONNECTION


# Mark filename as done in the SQLite DB
def mark_as_done(filename):
    connection = get_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO processed_files VALUES (?)', (filename,))


# Check of the file were already processed
def new_file(filename):
    connection = get_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM processed_files WHERE file=%s', (filename,))
    return cursor.rowcount == 0


# Yields filenames of files that were not processed yet
def new_files(path):
    for filename in glob.glob(path + '*.csv'):
        if new_file(filename):
            yield filename


# Mock of the transform process
def trasnform(data):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,3]})
```

Questions:

- When I put a file in the input directory, and fire the Load task, it doesn't fire the Extract task. What am I doing wrong?
- Will the Load fire every time using this `update_id` argument?

Comment: Why the code is indented with 4 spaces and isn't showing up as formatted code?

Comment: Because it was assumed to be part of the block in the 4th bullet.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it

Answer (score 0):

Your `Load` task is only creating `Transform` tasks when files exist in the `result/` directory. Shouldn't it be looking for new files in the `input` directory?

Comment: Not the problem, still doesn't fire the up the requirements. This was a typo when changing the names of the real folders I'm using